# how to get total variance explained by each principal component

Tags: r

I have created a PCA plot using:

```
library(SNPRelate)
library(gdsfmt)
vcf.fn <- "input.vcf"
snpgdsVCF2GDS(vcf.fn, "test.gds", method="biallelic.only")
snpgdsSummary("test.gds")
genofile <- snpgdsOpen("test.gds")
pop_code <- read.gdsn(index.gdsn(genofile, "genotype"))
snpset <- snpgdsLDpruning(genofile, autosome.only=FALSE, ld.threshold=0.2, maf= 0.01, missing.rate=0.5)
snpset.id <- unlist(snpset)
pca <- snpgdsPCA(genofile, autosome.only=FALSE, snp.id=snpset.id, num.thread=2)
pc.percent <- pca$varprop*100
head(round(pc.percent, 2))
tab <- data.frame(sample.id = pca$sample.id,
                  EV1 = pca$eigenvect[,1],    # the first eigenvector
                  EV2 = pca$eigenvect[,2],    # the second eigenvector
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
plot(tab$EV2, tab$EV1, xlab="eigenvector 2", ylab="eigenvector 1")
```

PCA plot looks like:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBeKT.png

I have created a matrix representing sample names (in rows) and first five PC's (in columns):

```
sample.id   EV1 EV2 EV3 EV4 EV5
1   T11 -0.007433146    -0.038371106    0.079585181  0.069839389    0.12178713
2   T3      -0.014198086    0.069641911     0.006414285  -0.004750456   0.046201258
3   T10     -0.086656303    0.026455731     -0.028758639 -0.015004286   -0.007497732
4   T162    -0.00520634     0.053996842     0.021754194  -0.004660844   0.006939661
5   T163    -0.020055447    0.027697494     -0.006933852 -0.058596466   0.028236645
```

I want to check how much variation is explained by each PC component. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It looks like it is saved in the pca object as pca$varprop?

Comment: I really don't understand what for all these code/packages needed for. In R, you can easily do what you need with a simple code. For instance `summary(prcomp(mtcars))` will give you the proportion of variance of each eigenvector (for the `mtcars` data, for instance).

Comment: @DavidArenburg this is genetic data loaded in from a specific kind of genetic data input file. You cannot simply just use the inbuilt prcomp function for it.

Comment: @4galaxy7, thank you! I got this: > pca$varprop
  [1] 0.014354586 0.012810173 0.009776336 0.008024355 0.007535734 0.007226178
  [7] 0.007111462 0.006306912 0.006254793 0.006037299 0.005681569 0.005466359
 [13] 0.005425150 0.005320071 0.005315401 0.005104559 0.004926057 0.004882665
 [19] 0.004817509 0.004797688 0.004780413 0.004694254 0.004679627 0.004642178
 [25] 0.004617999 0.004576135 0.004548338 0.004520876 0.004489281 0.004477552
 [31] 0.004430295 0.004420918 and rest NaN. Is it normal as the variance explained is not a lot.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing about your data. However, it isn't unusually for principle components from genetic data to explain small amounts of variation.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate residuals of these principal components. Thank you!